Error in vercel while uploading a django app
While trying to upload my Django application I got these errors
requirements.txt error: subprocess-exited-with-error × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully
Error: Command failed: pip3.12 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path0/requirements.txt
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

how do I come about it?
This is what I have in my vercel.json file:
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "ecommerce/wsgi.py",
            "use": "@vercel/python",
            "config": {
                "maxLambdaSize": "15mb",
                "runtime": "python3.9"
            }
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "ecommerce/wsgi.py"
        }
    ]
}

and these are the packages in my requirements.txt file:
Django==4.1.5
django-phonenumber-field==7.3.0
mysqlclient==2.2.4
numpy==1.26.4
phonenumbers==8.13.36
psycopg2==2.9.9
requests==2.31.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
twilio==9.0.5


I have tried using a virtual env but still didn't work and I also changed the python version from 3.10 to 3.9 in the vercel.json file also didn't work.

I was able to diagnose the issue and find the problem this required me to check the build logs in the Vercel one more time and then I found this:
 Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully. │ exit code: 1 ╰─> [21 lines of output] running egg_info writing psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO writing dependency_links to psycopg2.egg-...

It was actually a package that's not compatible with Vercel that package was psycopg2 so what I did:
I installed in binary version of the package psycopg2-binary and added it to my requirements.txt I redeployed, and everything worked out. It turns out that vercel his issues with some packages you will have to install the binary version like I did or install a previous version. Hope this can help anyone running into similar problem.
